# How to Sync Backend server with google sign-in

Tags: android, rest, backend, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

This is more of a theoretical question.

I have implemented a google sign in button in my app, and after that am able to show the name,email id of the logged in person in the activity.

Question:

1. I want to login and then create a record for the same on my backend server. How to do that? There is something called OAuth. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer
2. I want another table in the backend server with additional info for the user but that should be in sync(Let's say whenever the user open's the app, 1 point will be awarded,the point will be in another table, so how should I do that?) Rest API ?
3. Is there any differene in facebook's sign-in and google's sign-in.

I landed upon this question : [Google+ Sign In cross client(android/web) authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850836/google-sign-in-cross-clientandroid-web-authentication) but am not able to understand it totally.

Basically I want to login using google plus sign in and fetch additional data for that user and show it in my app. Any help will be appreciated. Links/Tutorials will be very helpful.